# Convert String into json array object...android

Tags: android, json, arrays

I get from the server array of objects, and by this code I convert it to json:

```
public static ArrayList<bussListCubic> parseBussinessArray(String result) {
    ArrayList<bussListCubic> arr = new ArrayList<bussListCubic>();
        try {
          JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
          JSONObject json_data = null;
          for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
             json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         bussListCubic userInfo = parseBussListCubic(json_data);
         arr.add(userInfo);
      }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return arr;
```

}

Some times the app crashed and this is the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116) at
org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94) at
org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87) at
org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
```

it is also point that the error with this line :
`JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result)`: line #4 in the above code...what does this error mean ?

thank you

Comment: The error is the most common error there is. It means that something is `null`, and you're trying to use that object as if it wasn't.

Comment: ok, But how you explain that the app most of the time work perfect, and sometimes it crashed !!

Comment: Please Check the json before looping it. Check it if it contain data then only use it.

Comment: Because sometimes it's null, and sometimes it isn't. There's nothing magic going on :p

Comment: so How could I check if the result contain data !!!

Comment: the result I got from the server, so do you mean that sometimes the server doesn't send the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crash is caused by an invalid `String result`

print the result passed to `parseBussinessArray` method and see what is its value when crash happens

Comment: actually I also try to send wrong result data"Just for test it", and the app doesn't crash, it just doesn't display anything!!!

Comment: If you use a try catch the error is masked, for this reason the app doesn't crash but doesn't show the values, with wrong input

Comment: actually now i just try to send null result to parseBussinessArray and I got the same error, so some times the app send null result !!

Comment: I don't know the way you pass result to this method but surely the issue is before, and when result is null cause this problem. You should manage the problem before invoking `parseBussinessArray`, adding the appropriate checks